# Как отследить, что пользователь прокрутил скролл вниз или вверх на странице где нет скролл-бара ?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как отследить, что пользователь прокрутил скролл вниз или вверх на странице где нет скролл-бара ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
    delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
    if (delta >= 0) {
      $('#result').html('Вверх');
    } else {
      $('#result').html('Вниз');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: не могу понять, почему ваш код не работает у меня: http://codepen.io/lexxl/pen/WrwJeJ - слегка изменил для наглядности, т.к. оригинал тоже не работал

Comment: вверх — красное. вниз — зеленое. работает. Браузер?

Comment: видимо, дело таки в нём. не работает в firefox 42.0, проверил в chrome 47 - цвет меняет. как быть?

Comment: обновил ответ. добавлено больше вариантов `bind`, добавлено для FF

Answer (score 1):

Как то так например

```
var wheel_handle = null;

var mouse_wheel = function(event) {
    if (false == !!event) event = window.event;
    var direction = ((event.wheelDelta) ? event.wheelDelta/120 : event.detail/-3) || false;
    if (direction && !!wheel_handle && typeof wheel_handle == "function") {
        wheel_handle(direction);
    }
}

var set_handle = function(id, func) {
    document.getElementById(id).onmouseover = function() {
        wheel_handle = func;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).onmouseout = function() {
        wheel_handle = null;
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouse_wheel, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = mouse_wheel;
}
```

Comment: Дмитрий, можете пожалуйста детально прокомментировать этот код, мне как новичку почти ничего не понятно к сожалению.

Comment: Вот статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/133321/ от автора решения ловли прокрутки на любых элементах.

Comment: Автор кода идиот, завязывается на настройки по умолчанию и не знает о существвовании мышей со свободным скроллом. 120 и 3 — это не магические константы.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > scrollTop){
        console.log("Down");
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    } else{
        console.log("Up");
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    }
});
```

Как вариант